# What categories are selected by default in Spotlight Search Results?

Tags: spotlight

I am running MacOS Big Sur.

I have modified the selected categories in **System Preferences** > **Spotlight** > **Search Results** some time ago.

Now, I am wondering what the default selected categories are. There is no reset to default button. I could not find this information by googling so far.

I am wondering if there is an online official document somewhere to specify what default categories are.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you log in with a new user, don't you get back to Spotlight's default preferences?

Comment: @Jean_JD thanks a lot for the comment and tip. I think you are right. But I didn't plan to create a new user for this purpose. I will think about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all categories are enabled.

Verified by installing macOS fresh into a VM, but it's been this way for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have upvoted your answer. Btw, I am wondering if installing macOS into a VM will burn your device or not. :)

Comment: @sgon00 , I am kind of a VM hobbyist (QEMU, VBox, vMac, etc.). I use Macs fan control (I personally use start at 60 c and full blast at 69 c on cpu core average) to keep my temps in check and prevent thermal throttling, which reduces the performance of the VM. It seems to work good (Macs Fan Control). BTW, I use a 2017 iMac, which I recently upgraded to. Before that, I used a 2013 iMac which had a transistor failure and would have a high chance of crashing after 60c. Macs fan control helped me here.

Comment: No worries. Thanks a lot for your comment and information. 